# Azure CLI - CosmosDB partition key path doesn't work without '/$v' before and after

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I had been banging my head against the wall trying to insert documents into partitioned collections in a Mongo API CosmosDB when the collection was created with the API, I was finally able to get my answer using this link:

[ComosDB - MongoAPI - Document does not contain shard key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45587691/comosdb-mongoapi-document-does-not-contain-shard-key)

But the solution just raised more questions for me.  My issue was that if I tried to create a partition key on /genericKey the creation of the collection would work fine, but when I would try to insert I got the error  "does not contain shard key"

When I would create it from within the mongo client or within the portal it worked fine.  I finally realized by running "az cosmosdb collection show" against my collecitons that on the ones created using the portal and the mongo client, the partition key path was actually "/'$v'genericKey/'$v'" and on the ones that I created using the CLI it was just "/genericKey"

So my workaround was to put the full string of "/'$v'genericKey/'$v'" into my CLI command, my question is what is the significance of the /'$v'at the beginning and the end?  Why do I have to add it?