# How to open authenticated connection to Cosmos DB emulator with Mongodb shell?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi, mongodb-shell

When I run

```
mongo --port 10255 --ssl
```

I get a connection to Cosmos db emulator in Mongodb mode. When I in that shell try to run

```
db.runCommand( { shardCollection: "myDB.myCollection", key: { myId: "hashed" } })
```

I get

> {
>           "_t" : "OKMongoResponse",
>           "ok" : 0,
>           "code" : 13,
>           "errmsg" : "Not Authenticated",
>           "$err" : "Not Authenticated"
>   }

If I try to open the connection with the connectiong string I use in .net

```
mongo mongodb://localhost:C2y6yDjf5/R+ob0N8A7Cgv30VRDJIWEHLM+4QDU5DE2nQ9nDuVTqobD4b8mGGyPMbIZnqyMsEcaGQy67XIw/Jw==@localhost:10255/admin?ssl=true
```

I get

> FailedToParse: Bad digit "C" while parsing C2y6yDjf5

How can I open up a shell to the cosmos db emulator to create a new collection as specified in this answer [ComosDB - MongoAPI - Document does not contain shard key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45587691/comosdb-mongoapi-document-does-not-contain-shard-key)