# MongoDb C# Driver Resolving Command insert failed: document does not contain shard key

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, azure-cosmosdb

I am experimenting with MongoDB Api for CosmosDB and I have the following error while inserting a value in the database :

> Command insert failed: document does not contain shard key.

I'm using cosmosdb emulator, My Partition Key is "Id" Here is a simple insert I tried :

```
        mongoCollection.InsertOne(new { Name = "John", Id = 007 });
```

To resolve this issue, I searched and saw this question :

[Similar to mine,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45587691/comosdb-mongoapi-document-does-not-contain-shard-key)

I tried running the command specified in the answer to the question, as follows :

```
        var command = new BsonDocument("{ shardCollection: \"Mydb.collection1\", key: { Id: \"hashed\" } }", 1);
        database.RunCommand<BsonDocument>(command);
```

But it doesn't work and throws me another exception, Please can someone tell me what to do ?

Comment: Any luck ? I'm stuck with similar situation

Comment: @JalalEl-Shaer Not yet, I have no solution. So I decided to work on a local MongoDB using the normal shell installation.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to fix the problem by creating a collection different ways via azure portal, shell, programmatically. Nothing helped me. Eventually I modified this sample https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-cosmos-db-mongodb-dotnet-getting-started which created collecton automatically on insert.